# javafx - how to bind service result to form fields?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

In the following example, how do I bind the service result to the textfield, so if i call service.restart() it would update the field?

Is the the correct way to do this, or the usual is to have the properties on the service class?

```
public class FormData {
    private StringProperty description = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public String getDescription() {
        return description.get();
    }

    public StringProperty descriptionProperty() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description.set(description);
    }
}


public class FormDataService extends Service<FormData> {

    @Override
    protected Task<FormData> createTask() {
        return new Task<FormData>() {
            protected FormData call() throws Exception {
                //database query here
                FormData data = new FormData();
                data.setDescription("Test Description");

                return data;
            }
        };
    }
}


public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private TextField textField;


    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        FormDataService service = new FormDataService();

        //HOW DO I BIND THE SERVICE RESULT TO THE TEXTFIELD?
    }
}
```

Comment: `textField.textProperty().bind(service.valueProperty().asString());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably FormData may have many fields and for each one you should have the corresponding TextField control, correct?
May be the listening of service property will be suitable for your case:

```
service.valueProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue != null) {
        textField.setText(newValue.getDescription());
        textField2.setText(newValue.getOtherData());
        // etc
    } else {
        // reset your fields
    }
});
```